# What is the easiest way to use npm package in django project?

Tags: django, npm

I have a django project which I want to use one specific npm package as a part of it (the package - https://www.webcomponents.org/element/roxus/range-datepicker).

Now, I really don't know nothing about npm, just django (and python, js, css, HTML), and don't want to spend a lot of time just to learn how to handle with npm and integrate it with django.

So, is there an easy option for me to take this specific package and serve it as static?